# Sudo command issue on CentOS 7.2

Tags: linux, bash, centos-7

I am running one script as **root** user (It prints "Hi" **with sudo** and "Bye" **without sudo**) from my test service which is located at `/etc/systemd/system/`. In the output I am unable to see **"Hi"** which was executed with sudo whereas **"Bye"** is there which was executed without sudo.

Any idea why commands with sudo are not working?

Comment: Show us a) the relevant entry from `/etc/sudoers` or `/etc/sudoers.d`, b) the contents of your script, and c) the systemd unit file for your service. If possible, take a look at [how to ask a good question](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to format your question properly](http://superuser.com/help/formatting).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If sudo does not have a TTY (e.g. running from a service) it will not work by default. Check *`/etc/sudoers`*: **Defaults requiretty**

PS: I got this answer on some other forum. It worked for me.